# ExtJS: How to wrap text in a ListView with columns?

Tags: listview, extjs, word-wrap

I have an **ExtJS** *ListView control* with 4 columns. One of the columns contain text which extends the width of the column, thus some of the text are located beneath the next column.

[image: Example image]

How can I set `white-space` to `normal` for the cells in the listview?

Comment: Did you try setting it in template (`tpl` property of column config object). If yes, then how?

Comment: **@Mchl:** No I haven't tried on the column config object - only on the entire ListView Control. I should have read your comment properly :$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be in your column definition:

```
{
    header: 'Besked',
    dataIndex: 'besked',
    tpl: '<p style=\"white-space:normal\";>{besked}</p>'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Sdavids solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635608/extjs-how-to-wrap-text-in-a-listview-with-columns/3730408#3730408) works and I voted for that.

But just in case you prefer **using a css class instead of styles** this is how:

```
{
    header: 'Besked',
    dataIndex: 'besked',
    cls: 'listViewColumnWrap'
}
```

Then you need this line in some **css file**:

```
.listViewColumnWrap { white-space:normal; }
```

Comment: Actually, it would be better to just add the cls to the column instead of wrapping it in a data template.

Answer (score 1):

This is a cross-browser way to override the default css classes to make all of your list views, grids, and combobox select menus all wrap their text content:

```
.x-list-body dt {white-space: normal;}
.x-list-body dt em { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}
.x-grid3-row-flag { white-space: normal; background-color: #ffc; }
.x-grid3-cell-inner, .x-grid3-hd-inner{ white-space: normal; }
.x-grid3-cell-inner { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}
.x-combo-list-inner .x-combo-list-item { white-space: normal; }
.x-combo-list-item { white-space: pre-wrap !important; word-wrap: break-word !important;}
```